# how to solver actual and formal argument lists differ in length error in Admob

Tags: admob

error: method show in class InterstitialAd cannot be applied to given types;
ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.show();
^
required: Activity
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
public void interstitialAdMobAd() {
    if (ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd != null) {
        if (ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            Log.d("shsjks", "sdhsjkhd");
            ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`show` method of `InterstitialAd` requires `Activity` as a param, see the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/interstitial/InterstitialAd#show(android.app.Activity)).

So you need something like:

```
ActivityHome.getInstance().mInterstitialAd.show(ActivityHome.getInstance());
```